# ESP32 String.reserve() why is not reflected on the RAM usage in compilation?

Tags: arduino, esp32

I'm using VS code with Platformio and I notice a strange? thing.

```
String evilString;

void setup(){
evilString.reserve(100)
}
```

And I compile it, I get this result:

```
Advanced Memory Usage is available via "PlatformIO Home > Project Inspect"
RAM:   [=         ]  14.2% (used 46380 bytes from 327680 bytes)
Flash: [=======   ]  74.2% (used 971985 bytes from 1310720 bytes)
```

If I run the memory inspect, i get a 80% of occupation.

If I run the `ESP.getFreeHeap()` I have a 42% of ram free.

I'm wrong telling that `.reserve()` use with empty block the ram lenght I pass to the function or not??

Comment: String uses dynamic allocation/reallocation on heap. the reserve is applied at runtime

Comment: can you explain better?

Answer (score 2):

Heap is allocated *dynamically* during runtime, meaning that it only allocates memory when you are running the program, it does not show up during the compilation.

`ESP.getFreeHeap()` gives the total available *free* memory that can be used for both stack and heap memory. For ESP32, with the 512KB memory, roughly about 320KB can be used for stacks and heap. Read [DRAM](https://ocs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/memory-types.html#dram-data-ram) of Memory Types for details.

In order to see the effect of `String.reserve()`, you need to call `ESP.getFreeHeap()` before and after calling `String.reserve()` method. BTW, the minimum allocation for a `String` is 16-byte, even for an empty string like `String myString{""};`, the allocation is in the multiple of 16 bytes (and in multiple of 32 bytes after 128), so `String.reverse(100)` will reserve 128 bytes instead of 100 bytes.

```cpp
String myString{""};

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(1000);

  Serial.println(ESP.getFreeHeap());
  myString.reserve(100);
  Serial.println(ESP.getFreeHeap());
}

void loop() {

}
```

Here is the result shows on my ESP32, you see the free heap shrinked by 128 bytes:

```
349188
349060
```